# vírgula entre os arrays

Tags: php

Estou trazendo as seguintes informações de um formulário:

```
$seg = "Seg";
$ter = "Ter";
$qua = "Qua";
$qui = "Qui";
```

Só que em muitos casos, alguns desses campos virão vazios, ex.:

```
$seg = "Seg";
$ter = "Ter";
$qua = "";
$qui = "Qui";
```

Gostaria de pegar essas informações e colocar vírgula entre as palavras, dessa forma:

```
Seg,Ter,Qui
```

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas não funcionou:

```
$diasPromocoes = $seg.",".$ter.",".$qua.",".$qui;
$dividir = explode(",",$diasPromocoes); 
echo implode(",",$dividir);
```

Está retornando:

```
Seg,Ter,,Qui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$diasPromocoes = array($seg,$ter,$qua,$qui);

// O array_filter com callback vai limpar os campos vazios do array
$diasPromocoes = array_filter($diasPromocoes, function($item){ 
    return !empty($item);
});

echo implode(',', $diasPromocoes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca num array as variáveis e faz o `implode`.

[Exemplo](https://ideone.com/pyFbME)

```
<?php

$arr = ['Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Sexta'];

echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode transformar as variáveis em uma array e usar a função `array_filter`:

```
$diasPromocoes = array($seg,$ter,$qua,$qui);
$arrayLimpa = array_filter($diasPromocoes);
echo arrayLimpa;
```